# Script to load contents of my XML file into array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I have an XML file, which can be viewed [here,](http://www.quickfilepost.com/download.do?get=db870d11eaf71077b7e7adffe570a747) of data concerning a series of music albums, which I would like to load into javascript into an array called "mymusic" in this form:

```json
mymusic = [
  {
    title:,
    artist:,
    artwork:,
    tracks: [
      {
        tracktitle:,
        trackmp3:
      },
      {
        tracktitle:,
        trackmp3:
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

etc.; so basically an array of albums, where each album is represented by a record, the fields of which are the album title, album artist, album artwork, and an array of the album's tracks (where each track/index of the array is represented by a record with fields tracktitle and trackmp3.

In order to achieve this I have the following javascript:

```js
function getxml(){
    xmldoc = XML.load('music.xml');

    var xmlalbums = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('album');
    mymusic = [];
    for(i = 0; i < xmlalbums.length; i++){
        xmlalbum = xmlalbums[i];
        mymusic[i] = {};
        mymusic[i].title = dataFromTag(xmlalbum,'title');
        mymusic[i].artist = dataFromTag(xmlalbum,'artist');
        mymusic[i].artwork = dataFromTag(xmlalbum, 'artwork');
        tracks = [];

        var xmltracks = xmlalbums[i].getElementsByTagName('track');
        for(var a = 0; a < xmltracks.length; a++){
            xmltrack = xmltracks[i];
            tracks[i] = {};
            tracks[i].tracktitle = dataFromTag(xmltrack, 'title');
            tracks[i].trackmp3 = dataFromTag(xmltrack, 'mp3');
            mymusic[i].tracks = tracks;
        }
    }
}
```

however, this doesn't load the contents of music.xml in the way I'd like, but I can't see why this is. Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, where do we see the xml file? Are we suppose to click on something on that page?

Comment: Edited the link to work. Do you have any idea what's wrong with my javascript?

Comment: Couple more questions: When you say "this doesn't load the contents" the way you'd like, what is currently happening?

Comment: As an aside, this isn't really an answer to your question, but be careful in general with declaring variables in JavaScript. I'm only guessing, but I believe you may want to make sure mymusic, xmlalbum, tracks and xmltrack all get a 'var' placed before them in your function.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.
When i put an alert(mymusic) in, it actually gives a series of 4 alerts in succession: the first is "[object Object]" the second "[object Object],[object Object]" and so on to alert no. 4. I have checked that the alert is not nested in the for-loop so it can't be to do with that.
And for your second point...I'll give it a go, in the vain hope it changes something!
Thanks

Comment: Why would you leave out `dataFromTag` from your question? Seems kinda important...

Comment: Sorry? I'm not quite sure what you're saying

Answer (score 0):

that's should work

```js
function getxml(){
    xmldoc = XML.load('music.xml');

    var xmlalbums = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('album');
    mymusic = [];
    for(i = 0; i < xmlalbums.length; i++){
        xmlalbum = xmlalbums[i];
        mymusic[i] = {};
        mymusic[i].title = dataFromTag(xmlalbum,'title');
        mymusic[i].artist = dataFromTag(xmlalbum,'artist');
        mymusic[i].artwork = dataFromTag(xmlalbum, 'artwork');

        tracks = [];
        var xmltracks = xmlalbums[i].getElementsByTagName('track');
        for(var a = 0; a < xmltracks.length; a++){
            xmltrack = xmltracks[a];
            tracks[a] = {};
            tracks[a].tracktitle = dataFromTag(xmltrack, 'title');
            tracks[a].trackmp3 = dataFromTag(xmltrack, 'mp3');
        }

        mymusic[i].tracks = tracks;
    }
}
```

Comment: in advice you should use firefox with firebug extention
to help you debug your code with "console.log(your_variable)" function